# Laravel - return View::make vs $layout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Usually I have managed my layouts in Laravel like this:

**views/index.blade.php**

```
<html>
    <body>
        @yield('content')
    </body>
</html>
```

**views/main/root.blade.php**

```
@extends('index')

@section('content')
    <p>whatever</p>
@stop
```

**controllers/MainController.php**

```
class MainController extends \BaseController {

    public function root(){
        return View::Make('main.root');
    }

}
```

Now I am reading about the $layout variable. The documentation says:

> Your application probably uses a common layout across most of its
>   pages. Manually creating this layout within every controller action
>   can be a pain. Specifying a controller layout will make your
>   development much more enjoyable

But I do not see how this makes it more enjoyable.

This is the same code, but using the $layout variable:

**controllers/MainController.php**

```
class MainController extends \BaseController {

    public $layout = "index";

    public function root(){
        $this->layout->nest('content', 'main.root');
    }

}
```

Now, how is this easier? It seems like more code to me. Besides I have already stated that `root`blade extends `index` so it seems like there is duplication here.

I probably am getting something wrong about this technique. Can someone help me to make sense of it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been asking on IRC and it seems like this is actually coming from Laravel 3, and now @extends is the new way of doing things. So it appears `setupLayout` is sort of legacy code. So I guess I can safely ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up your BaseController: (Laravel calls `setupLayout()` automatically if it exists)

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
    }

}
```

You can just specify the `@section()` name as a property, not have to `@extend()` your views. and / or override the layout inherited form BaseController.

```
class MainController extends \BaseController {

    public function index(){
        $this->layout->content = View::make('main.index');
    }

}
```

**In your view:**

```
@section('content')

<div class="row-fluid">
    Test
</div>

@stop
```

**In the master layout:**

```
@yield('content')
```

Comment: That did not work as you explained... I got an error.

Comment: What's the error that you're getting? The answer's code looks fine to me.

Comment: Sure, just added views.  I also answered [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268785/using-blade-laravel-properly-having-problems-having-header-in-its-own-file/25270850#25270850) which may come in handy as it is regarding something similar.

Answer (score 1):

The point is

1. not having to specify `@extends` in every single view
2. The possibility to render the content section of a template individually, for example for an AJAX template or to re-use the content section in more than one layouts.

Whether or not it is actually good practice or if it saves you any pain is definitely arguable, but that's the idea behind it.